# How to have one dependency use another?

Tags: knockout.js

I have one property on my view model that is used in a `select` element. Bound to the value of this `select` is a chosenproduct.

Now I want a third property to use a field on the chosenproduct, but how do I do that?

I tried something like this, with no luck:

```
viewModel = {
    startDateAndTime: ko.observable(new Date()), 
    selectedProduct : products[0],
    endDateAndTime : ko.observable(new Date(this.startDateAndTime).add({minutes: this.selectedProduct.duration})) 
    //the rest goes here
```

The first two properties works fine, but the third is not working.

Comment: Just saw dependent observables. Need to try it out, I'll be back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be using dependent observables for this >

```
viewModel = {
            startDateAndTime: ko.observable(new Date()), 
            selectedProduct : products[0]
}


viewModel.endDateAndTime = ko.dependentObservable(function () {

return new Date(this.startDateAndTime).add({minutes: this.selectedProduct.duration}));

}, viewModel);
```

Important to note is that you can only add dependent observables once you have already declared the `viewModel` (e.g. above we declared `endDataAndTime` outside of `viewModel` declaration). Steve (the author of knockoutjs) [writes](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html) extensively why under the heading 'Managing this'.